# Checked input radio launch color transition in div (only css)

Tags: html, css

So, here is the deal.. I have a simple radio and a hidden div

```
<input type="radio" name="picture" id="radio-id" selected="false">
<label id="label-id" for="radio-id"></label>
<div class="some-class">
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
.some-class{
 position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;        
    display:none;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
         -o-transition: all 1s linear;
            transition: all 1s linear;
}
 #radio-id:checked ~ .some-class{
    display: block;
    background: rgb( 40, 44, 47 );
}
```

The problem here is that, when the radio is checked, there is no transition at all. The Div appears with the new background, but its not smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the css with the following

```
#radio-id:checked ~ .some-class {
   display: block;
   background: rgb( 40, 44, 47 );
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   opacity: 0.7;
   -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
   -o-transition: all 1s linear;
   transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know, this way is working fine,but first, the div has to be with display:none.. and then, display:block.. Its interesting, working fine with visibility:hidden/visible, but not with display:block/none..

Comment: so what is the reason you need to have it with display none?

Comment: also, css transitions is not possible between display none and display block.

Comment: Thank you, the last comment figuere out everything : )

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<html> 
<input type="radio" name="picture" id="radio-id" selected="false">
    <label id="label-id" for="radio-id"></label>
    <div class="some-class">
        hello
    </div>
</html>
```

Css

```
.some-class{
     position: fixed;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
        height:100px;
        width: 100px;        
        display:none;
        background: white;
        opacity: 0.7;
        -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
           -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
            -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
             -o-transition: all 1s linear;
                transition: all 1s linear;
    }
     #radio-id:checked ~ .some-class{
        display: block;
        background: rgb( 40, 44, 47 );
    }
```